# RaphaelJS animate does not work when called from an outside method

Tags: javascript, raphael

As a desktop developer I am very new to Javascript, so I often run into things that puzzle me about the language. I was working with click events on RaphaelJS shapes, and initially I was setting the state and animation of the object in a private method:

```
innershape.node.onclick = function () {
    if (scope.state === 0) {
        _setState(1);
    } else {
        _setState(0);
    }
};

function _setState(state) {
    scope.state = state;
    if (scope.state === 0) {
        innershape.animate({ fill: "#00FF19" }, 500);
    } else {
        innershape.animate({ fill: "#C05219" }, 500);
    }       
}
```

This was functioning as expected. I then decided to add an outside function that would loop through all the objects and de-select (and therefore reverse-animate) all the other shapes. The result may be seen in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/txj4zasn/4/

The function is called properly, and the animate() function is apparently executed, but the visible animation never appears, and the color never changes. I suspect that this is something very basic to Javascript that I just don't understand. Can someone explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: Colours change for me fine with the animation in the fiddle. Can you clarify what you are expecting to see vs what you see (maybe include browser & version)?

Comment: Sorry, I left un-commented the in-class call - see updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/txj4zasn/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not really very clear what you want to achieve (beyond getting the animation to work), so my initial solution I think isn't good, but I will expand on that.

The problem looks a bit like you are trying to combine two different elements, functional scope and object variables.

A quick solution would be to include...

```
this.id = 1; 
var id = this.id; // so id now a closure to the later function
```

as updateSelected(id); the id here, is inside another function, so we can't use 'this.id'. But then later you are checking against z[i].id so you need that to be defined also.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/txj4zasn/5/)

This all feels a bit clunky though, prone to error, and is quite hard to read. So the first question is do you need objects ? You could store information in the "data" part of a Raph element, which already is an object.

Here is an example of how I would write it, I appreciate this may not be suitable as it may be part of a bigger project which needs other elements in an object, but it may give some idea.

```
function updateSelected( el ) {
    if( el.data('innerstate') == 1 ) {
        el.animate({ fill: "#00FF19" }, 500);
        el.data('innerstate',0)
    } else {
        el.animate({ fill: "#C05219" }, 500);
        el.data('innerstate',1);
    }

}

function addElement() {
    var innershape = paper.rect(100,100,100, 100);
    innershape.attr({fill: "#00FF19" });
    innershape.data('innerstate', 0);
    innershape.click( function () {
        updateSelected( innershape )
    } );

};

addElement();
```

This code I can pretty much read instantly and know how and if it will work.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/txj4zasn/9/)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/txj4zasn/10/) showing it combined with more than one element, or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/txj4zasn/12/) thats a bit more compact

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - that solves my key issue. What I am trying to achieve is the ability to deselect any other objects when I click this one. Your solution here has taken me a long way towards that goal - thanks for the clarity and patience.

Comment: Here is an updated example that includes a toggle to switch colors of inactive element http://jsfiddle.net/txj4zasn/15/